# Java 8 group list of objects with list inside

Tags: java, list, java-8, grouping

I've two objects in my java project that are something like this:

```
FavoriteGroup
- int id
- string userId
- string name
- List<Favorite> favorites
```

and

```
Favorite
- int id
- int groupId
- string title
- string path
```

Now, I've a List of items that may repeat the groups.
Do I have a way to group that list in a way that for each FavoriteGroup I've all my Favorite list joined?

More graphical explanation:
I've:

```
[{ 
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    name: "Group one",
    favorites: [{
       id: 100,
       groupId: 1,
       title: "Favorite 1",
       path: "path 1" 
    }]

 },
{ 
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    name: "Group one",
    favorites: [{
       id: 200,
       groupId: 1,
       title: "Favorite 2",
       path: "path 2" 
    }]

 },
{ 
    id: 2,
    userId: 1,
    name: "Group two",
    favorites: [{
       id: 300,
       groupId: 2,
       title: "Favorite 3",
       path: "path 3" 
    }]

 }]
```

And I need:

```
[{ 
        id: 1,
        userId: 1,
        name: "Group one",
        favorites: [{
           id: 100,
           groupId: 1,
           title: "Favorite 1",
           path: "path 1" 
        },
       {
           id: 200,
           groupId: 1,
           title: "Favorite 2",
           path: "path 2" 
        }]

     },
    { 
        id: 2,
        userId: 1,
        name: "Group two",
        favorites: [{
           id: 300,
           groupId: 2,
           title: "Favorite 3",
           path: "path 3" 
        }]

     }]
```

What's the best way to do this? using for loop iterations or maybe grouping java 8 stream functions?

Comment: Build a `Map` keyed by `id` and decide whether a secondary group should update values or not, in case the multiple definitions of the same group has different values.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do it like so,

```
private static final String DELIMITER = "-";

Map<String, List<Favorite>> favsByGroup = favGroups.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g -> g.getId() + DELIMITER + g.getUserId() + DELIMITER + g.getName(),
            Collectors.flatMapping(fg -> fg.getFavorites().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
List<FavoriteGroup> mergedFavoriteGroups = favsByGroup.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new FavoriteGroup(Integer.parseInt(e.getKey().split(DELIMITER)[0]),
        e.getKey().split(DELIMITER)[1], e.getKey().split(DELIMITER)[2], e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First create a map taking the concatenated Id, userId and name properties of `FavoriteGroup` as the key and the `List` of `Favorite` instances as the value. Then for each entry in the map, I'll create a new `FavoriteGroup` by decoding the key and passing the values as it is. As a final step `collect` the resulting objects to a container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
favoriteGroups.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(FavoriteGroup::getId, Function.identity(), (fg1, fg2) -> {
            //This will modify the original object(s). If you don't want that, then you'll have to clone the object and set favorites.
            fg1.setFavorites(Stream.concat(fg1.getFavorites().stream(), fg2.getFavorites().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            return fg1;
        }))
        .values();
```

This will return an object of type `Collection<FavoriteGroup>`, which you can iterate over. If you want to convert it back to `List`, you can do `List<FavoriteGroup> list = new ArrayList<>(favoriteGroupsCollection);`.

Comment: With this approach, you are modifying the favorite lists of the original favorite groups, you need to make a copy instead of using function identity.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I had flagged this in my answer and provided a solution to that too. I think you didn't see the comment inside the code block.